# Kubernetes: Error kubectl edit deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to edit deployment in kubernetes by:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> edit deployment <depolyment_name>.
```

after entering the command, vi windows for editing appears, then I make some changes for example in the command section or in volumeMounts section.

but I get the following error:

```
A copy of your changes has been stored to "/tmp/kubectl-edit-hv5dh.yaml"
error: map: map[] does not contain declared merge key: name
```

someone can help with it?

attached the edit deployment file of apiserver:

kubectl -n federation-system edit deployment apiserver

(codes between **   ** are the lines i added)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    federation.alpha.kubernetes.io/federation-name: fed
  creationTimestamp: 2018-04-01T13:26:40Z
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: federated-cluster
  name: apiserver
  namespace: federation-system
  resourceVersion: "393140"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/federation-system/deployments/apiserver
  uid: <uid>
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: federated-cluster
      module: federation-apiserver
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        federation.alpha.kubernetes.io/federation-name: fed
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: federated-cluster
        module: federation-apiserver
      name: apiserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /fcp
        - federation-apiserver
        - --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle
        - --advertise-address=<master-ip>
        - --bind-address=0.0.0.0
        - --client-ca-file=/etc/federation/apiserver/ca.crt
        - --etcd-servers=http://localhost:2379
        - --secure-port=8443
        - --tls-cert-file=/etc/federation/apiserver/server.crt
        - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/federation/apiserver/server.key
        **- --enable-admission-plugins=SchedulingPolicy
        - --admission-control-config-file=/etc/kubernetes/admission/config.yml**
        image: gcr.io/k8s-jkns-e2e-gce-federation/fcp-amd64:v1.9.0-alpha.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: apiserver
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: https
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: local
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/federation/apiserver
          name: apiserver-credentials
          readOnly: true
        **volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/admission
          name: admission-config**
      - command:
        - /usr/local/bin/etcd
        - --data-dir
        - /var/etcd/data
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:3.1.10
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: etcd
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
      - {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: apiserver-credentials
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: apiserver-credentials
      **- name: admission-config
        configMap:
          name: admission**
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: 2018-04-01T13:26:40Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2018-04-01T13:26:40Z
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: 2018-04-01T13:26:40Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2018-04-01T13:27:20Z
    message: ReplicaSet "apiserver-8484fd45f8" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

it's happened after I created configMap file:

```
kubectl create -f scheduling-policy-admission.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: admission
  namespace: federation-system
data:
  config.yml: |
    apiVersion: apiserver.k8s.io/v1alpha1
    kind: AdmissionConfiguration
    plugins:
    - name: SchedulingPolicy
      path: /etc/kubernetes/admission/scheduling-policy-config.yml
  scheduling-policy-config.yml: |
    kubeconfig: /etc/kubernetes/admission/opa-kubeconfig
  opa-kubeconfig: |
    clusters:
      - name: opa-api
        cluster:
          server: http://opa.federation-system.svc.cluster.local:8181/v0/data/kubernetes/placement
    users:
      - name: scheduling-policy
        user:
          token: deadbeefsecret
    contexts:
      - name: default
        context:
          cluster: opa-api
          user: scheduling-policy
    current-context: default
```

I'm trying to configure Admission Controller in the Federation API.

Thanks,

Comment: There's a syntax error in it after you edit it. You need to paste the contents of the deployment for anyone to help

Comment: idk, configmap looks right, maybe extra `volumeMounts` key instead of an item under it?

Comment: i tried both. i'm not sure is syntax error because the issue was also when I tried to change the name or port or something else.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  # DELETE imagePullSecrets:
  # DELETE - {}
  restartPolicy: Always
```

I would strongly recommend removing that `imagePullSecrets` block. Since those objects have a mergeKey of `name`, but that object has no `name`, it would very easily cause the error you are experiencing. If the YAML was given to your editor in that condition, then I am almost certain that is a kubernetes bug: it should always(?) allow round-tripping YAML via `kubectl edit`, if for no other reason than this situation right here.

Comment: in that case, please do consider marking this answer as correct, since it will help others know (a) your question is resolved (b) to look here if they have a similar question

Comment: Also, did `kubectl edit` open the YAML file in that condition? I am wondering if we need to find or open a bug for kubernetes sending down "illegal" YAML

Comment: what you mean in that condition?

Comment: Containing the erroneous content `imagePullSecrets:\n- {}\n`

Comment: after deleteing of
imagePullSecrets:\n- {}\n 

the connecting to the cluster trough federation control plane is gone.

maybe is related to this change?

command like
kubectl get namespace / get cluster return 
No resourse found
and there are error on controller manager container :

Comment: in addition the api-server container isn't created 
and when i delete the changes and return to initial state the container created but without connecting to cluster